# Grep hashes via regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, hash, grep

I want to grep for hexadecimal hashes in strings and only extract those hashes.

I've tested a regex in online regex testing tools that does the trick:

```
\b[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]+[0-9a-f]\b
```

The `\b` is used to set word boundaries (start & end) that should be any character `0-9` or `a-f`. Since I do not know if the hashes are 128bit or higher, I do not know the length of the hashes in advance. Therefore I set `[0-9a-f]+` in the middle in order match any number of `[0-9a-f]`, but at least one (since no hash consists just of two characters that are checked with the boundaries `\b`).

However, I noticed that

```
grep --only-matching -e "\b[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]+[0-9a-f]\b"
```

does not work in the shell, while the regex `\b[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]*[0-9a-f]\b` works in online regex testing tools.

In fact, the shell version does only work if I escape the quantifier `+` with a backslash:

```
grep --only-matching -e "\b[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\+[0-9a-f]\b"
                                           ^
                                           |_ escaped +
```

Why does `grep` needs this escaping in the shell?

Is there any downside of my rather simple approach?

Comment: you can also use `-w` option to match only words instead of having to use `\b`s

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why a metacharacter would need to be escaped in the bash, but your regex could be rewritten as this:

```
grep --only-matching -e "\b[0-9a-f]{3,}\b"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Do you know why this also matches to 3 character hexadecimals? I initially thought this should delimit the search string to hexadecimals that begin *and* end with at least 3 hexadecimals characters, thus the whole string should have at least length 6.

Comment: Your original regex implies you want to match 3 or more hex characters.  How many do you want to match?

Comment: 3 or more is totally correct, so your answer is good. Sorry, if my comment was ambiguous. I wanted to ask *why* this regex matches 3 characters or more, because I thought the double `\b` word boundaries should imply that the string has to start **and** end with 3 (or more) characters fulfilling `[0-9a-f]` (due to the quantification `{3,}`), so that the search string has to consist of at least 6 characters in total (3 for the start *and* 3 for the end).

Comment: A word boundary would not be treated as a hex character here AFAIK.  Rather, it would be the character which comes before the first hex (or `^` anchor), of the character coming after the last hex (or `$` anchor).

Answer (score 2):

The `+` quantifier is not part of the POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (aka BRE) so you must escape it with `grep` in BRE mode.

As an alternative, you can:

- add the `-E` flag to `grep`:
  `grep -E --only-matching -e "\b[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]+[0-9a-f]\b"`
- use `[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]*` or `[0-9a-f]{1,}`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Could you add a little explanation what POSIX compliant is? What is the difference between `-e` and `-E`? `man grep` only says `-e` searches for a regex, while `-E` is for extended regular expressions...what are extended regular expressions?

Comment: See [POSIX Basic and Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) to learn more about BRE and ERE.

Comment: Thank you very much! For the extended regex: shouldn't `grep --only-matching -E "\b[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]+[0-9a-f]\b"` be sufficient? Does combining `-E` and `-e` make a difference?

Comment: Just use `-E` in your case. `grep` waits for a pattern in any case. As `man grep` says, `-e` is for use when multiple patterns (eg `grep -e 'a' -e 'b')` or to grep string starting with an hyphen (eg `grep -e '-a')`. In that last case, without `-e`, `-a` could be interpreted as a flag by `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Grep runs basic regular expressions by default. You need to escape the `+` quantifier with a backslash as it is said in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html):

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`,
>   `(`, and `)` lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed
>   versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`.

Also, there is no need for `-e` option, just

```
grep -o '\b[0-9a-f]\+\b' file
```